# LEFT JOIN ignores ON clause and examines every row. WHY?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have the following queries

```
SELECT MAKEDATE( LEFT(IF(i_id = 0, Job.FillDate, BillingDate), 4 ) , 
       RIGHT( IF(i_id = 0, Job.FillDate, BillingDate), 3 ) ) as day, 
       IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(GREATEST((IF(i_id = 0 AND ISNULL(BillAmt), (PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), IF(ISNULL(BillAmt),(PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), (BillAmt+Cashpaid)))),0.00)),2),0.00) as total_pay, 
       Count(*) as total_transactions 
FROM `job` AS `Job` 
LEFT JOIN `jobtrak` AS `JobTrack` ON (
  `Job`.`id` = `JobTrack`.`job_id` 
  AND  IF(i_id = 0, `Job`.`FillDate`, BillingDate) BETWEEN 2014183 AND 2014212 
  AND LENGTH( CONV( Jobstatus, 10, 2 ) ) NOT IN ( 5, 6, 8 ) 
  AND `Job`.`Active` = 0 ) 
GROUP BY IF(i_id = 0, `Job`.`FillDate`, BillingDate);
```

The following query exhaust my mysql server and causes the page to never load on my application. So, I looked at the explain and it shows that the Job table is retrieving all 493345 records and the JobTrack table is getting all 286812 records from its table. Why is it doing this?? Any suggestions??

Comment: Some column references are qualified, a lot of them are not. Are we to assume that the unqualified column references refer to columns from the **`jobtrack`** table? (Best practice is to qualify ALL column refernces, wo the reader isn't left to consult the schema definition to find out which table a column appears in (or to make assumptions. e.g. `BillingDate`, `Jobstatus`, `i_id`, and others in expressions in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query, cleaned up a bit so I find it more readable:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE( LEFT(IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate), 4 ) , 
       RIGHT( IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate), 3 ) ) as day, 
       IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(GREATEST((IF(i_id = 0 AND ISNULL(BillAmt), (PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), IF(ISNULL(BillAmt),(PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), (BillAmt+Cashpaid)))),0.00)),2),0.00) as total_pay, 
       Count(*) as total_transactions 
FROM job j LEFT JOIN
     jobtrak jt
     ON j.id = jt.job_id AND
        IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate) BETWEEN 2014183 AND 2014212 AND
        LENGTH( CONV( Jobstatus, 10, 2 ) ) NOT IN ( 5, 6, 8 ) AND
        j.Active = 0 
GROUP BY IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate);
```

The expression `j.Active =0` in the `where` clause is doing *nothing*.  Because you have a `left join`, all rows are being returned from the `job` table, even when the predicate evaluates to false.  So, I suspect you mean:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE( LEFT(IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate), 4 ) , 
       RIGHT( IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate), 3 ) ) as day, 
       IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(GREATEST((IF(i_id = 0 AND ISNULL(BillAmt), (PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), IF(ISNULL(BillAmt),(PaidByPlan1+PaidByPlan2+Cashpaid), (BillAmt+Cashpaid)))),0.00)),2),0.00) as total_pay, 
       Count(*) as total_transactions 
FROM job j LEFT JOIN
     jobtrak jt
     ON j.id = jt.job_id AND
        IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate) BETWEEN 2014183 AND 2014212 AND
        LENGTH( CONV( Jobstatus, 10, 2 ) ) NOT IN ( 5, 6, 8 )
WHERE j.Active = 0 
GROUP BY IF(i_id = 0, j.FillDate, BillingDate);
```

And that `JobStatus` is in the `jobtrak` table.  If not, it too should be moved to the `where`.

The only indexes that will really help this is `jobtrack(job_id)` and `job(active)`.  The expression `LENGTH( CONV( Jobstatus, 10, 2 ) )` is quite unusually.  Comparing the length of a binary representation of a decimal number just isn't commonly done in most business application.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for clearing up the mysql. I changed everything to how you had it and moved the jobstatus to the where statement. The explain still returns the exact thing as the other statements have done. It is still returning all rows from Both tables for comparison.

Comment: The expression LENGTH( CONV( Jobstatus, 10, 2 ) ) has to be done because the information that I get back from the client's database is a bitfield representation.

Comment: I suspect that breaking up the query by `i.id` is probably the only way to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
`Job`.`id` = `Job`.`job_id`
```

You are joining with columns from same table

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. I fixed the type on here. It was correct on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The query is retrieving all rows from the `job` table because there aren't any predicates that restrict  the rows returned from that table. (The predicates that reference the table appear in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` operation, so those predicates only affect which rows are returned from the `jobtrack` table.)

As far as getting rows from the `jobtrak` table, it's likely that every row in that table "matches" a row from the `job` table. And that would be true if `job_trak.job_id` is non-NULL FOREIGN KEY that references `job.id`.

---

If you want to restrict rows returned from the `job` table, you'd need to include predicates in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I just did the where clause and it was the exact same. Nothing changed in the explain.